# Nginx не перераспределяет нагрузку при отключении одного из бекэндов

Tags: nginx

Мне нужно было сделать балансировщик на nginx, который распределяет нагрузку между бекэндами (nginx + rails). Столкнулся с проблемой, что при отключении одного из бекэндов nginx не перераспределяет нагрузку, т.е. нагрузка на оставшихся бекэндах остается та же, а RPS на балансировщике падает. Никак не могу понять в чем проблема.
Вот конфиг балансировщика:

```
upstream backend {
  server 10.132.0.2 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=30s;
  server 10.142.0.4 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=30s;
  server 10.142.0.5 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=30s;
  server 10.142.0.6 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=30s;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 0.0.0.0;
  root /app/public;
  allow all;

  location /nginx_status {
    stub_status;
  }

  location /assets/ {
    error_page 404 = @store;
    expires max;
  }

  location @store {
    proxy_store on;
    proxy_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_502;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

График RPS на балансировщике (синий) и бекэндах, отключается желтый бекэнд *(на нем сразу RPS падает до 0, на графике ошибка)*.
[image: График RPS]

Comment: Что-то непонятно как внешний RPS может зависеть от количества бекендов.

Comment: Тоже непонятно :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, на бекендах нужно было поправить конфиги: увеличить количество воркеров и выставить `multi_accept on;`. Сейчас все нормально работает.